# Why do composite materials not decrease the OEW

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, composite-materials

Boeing states in an article, that the 787 Dreamliner saves around 20% of weight in a comparison to an aluminium based aircraft. [Boeing 787 Dreamliner](https://simpleflying.com/787-a350-composite/)

When comparing the 787 Dreamliner to other "recently" introduced aircraft such as the A330-900 it does not seem that any weight has been saved. The A330-900 is an aluminium aircraft built on the A330-300.

| Aircraft | OEW | MTOW | Passenger Exit Limit | OEW/MTOW | OEW/Exit Limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B787-10 | 135t | 254t | 440 | 0.531 | 0.3068 |
| A330-900 | 135t | 251t | 460 | 0.537 | 0.2935 |

When comparing the OEW to the MTOW it seems, that both values are pretty similar. Given the same OEW, the A330-900 can carry 20 passengers more.

What could be the reason, why the A330-900 has a same structural efficiency as the 787 Dreamliner, despite not using any composites? Doesn't the 787 Dreamliner should have decreased the OEW by 20% hence having a much better ratio of OEW/Exit Limit?

Comment: Very much related: [What is the average weight difference between composite and metal airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46625/19). It probably answers your question.

Comment: If anybody wants to flag or vote to close as a duplicate, that would be good. I won't because that would mod-hammer it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the average weight difference between composite and metal airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46625/what-is-the-average-weight-difference-between-composite-and-metal-airliners)

Comment: This does not quite answer my questions, as it indicates, that weight savings from composites were used to build larger wings. Comparing the B787 and the A330-900 this is actually the opposite. The A330-900 has a 4m larger wingspan, using aluminium and still having a better structural efficiency.

Comment: Boeing's relationship with truth isn't not akin to an open marriage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why has structural efficiency (OEW / MTOW) not improved despite increasing use of carbon fiber?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/98616/why-has-structural-efficiency-oew-mtow-not-improved-despite-increasing-use-o)

Answer (score 2):

Composite fuselage weight savings aren't as good as a straight beam-to-beam comparison indicates. There are [design constraints other than structural load](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60909/why-dont-short-haul-regional-jets-go-for-composites), which limit what can be achieved.

Meanwhile, Airbus wasn't just doing nothing, small improvements do get implemented even on existing models of aircraft.

The 787-10 is a slightly larger aircraft than the A330-900. It's got fewer exits, but through an extra 9" in width and a longer cabin, packs more seats in practice.

It's hard to compare apples to apples, because airlines don't operate two competing types at once. That said, the 787-10 tends to pack [up to 310-344 seats](https://aviatechchannel.com/boeing-787-10-seat-map/) in long haul, while the A330-900 typically does 290-350 (various airlines). The 787-10 also carries up to 40 LD3 containers vs 33 on the A330-900.

So the few percent of improvement from composites is used to get space for more cargo and pax, at the expense of somewhat less range compared to the A330.

Comment: Another factor is that the knowledge of the theoretical structural savings tends to cause weight creep on other areas, as an almost subconscious relaxing of weight control. Sort of a moral hazard effect combined with "death by a thousand cuts" as tiny weight increments in a thousand different places add up.